# How to dynamically override __setitem__? (no subclass)

Tags: python, overriding, python-2.7, built-in

I'm not able to override some builtin functions, such as '__setitem__', in **Python2.7** (although the same occurs in previous versions I tested)

Although I know this is easy to do via subclassing, this is not what I want here, I need to be able to dynamically override these methods.

Apparently, when my class is a subclass of '**object**', the overridden method always ends up calling the original one, but when my class is not an '**object**', it works:

```
>>> def new_implementation(k, v):
...     print 'New implementation'
...

### class that extends object
>>> class ExtendsObject(object):
...     def __setitem__(self, k, v):
...             print 'ExtendsObject implementation'
...



### Checking implementation
>>> obj = ExtendsObject()
>>> obj[0]=0
ExtendsObject implementation

### trying to override setitem, no success
>>> obj.__setitem__ = new_implementation
>>> obj[0]=0
ExtendsObject implementation




### class that does NOT extends object
>>> class DoesNotExtend:
...     def __setitem__(self, k, v):
...             print 'DoesNotExtend implementation'
...

### Checking implementation
>>> obj_2 = DoesNotExtend()
>>> obj_2[0]=0
DoesNotExtend implementation

### overriding now works!
>>> obj_2.__setitem__ = new_implementation
>>> obj_2[0]=0
New implementation
```

For some reason, it seems that objects use some different method resolution order for these built-in functions.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For old-style classes, special methods were looked up on the instance each time they were needed.  New-style classes only look up special methods on the *type* of the instance, not in the instance's dictionary itself -- that's why you see the behaviour you see.

(In case you don't know --  a new-style class is a class directly or indirectly derived from `object`.)

Comment: For performance reasons I assume?

I guess there's no way around this, other than using old-style classes when I want to override those...

Comment: @campos.ddc: I'd stringly recommend against using old-style classes.  And there might be a way around this, but I will only tell you if you tell me what you are *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically, I have a 'listener' thing, in which I can register a function to be called whenever another function is called. Whenever my list is modified, I want to do something.

This listener is generic, it takes an instance, a method name, and the target method to be called after that one

Comment: @campos.ddc: To be honest, I don't really get your design.  Maybe you could just ask another question detailing the design with some code?

Answer (score 2):

As [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281542/577088) says, the problem is that for new-style classes, indexed assignment uses the `__setitem__` defined by the *class*. But it's not hard to get around this problem. The solution, as is so often the case, involves [another level of indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). This isn't a great design, but it seems like the obvious way to do what you want:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __setitem__(self, k, v):
...         return self._instance_setitem(k, v)
...     def _instance_setitem(self, k, v):
...         print 'old setitem'
... 
>>> def new_setitem(self, k, v):
...     print 'new setitem'
... 
>>> f[0] = 0
old setitem
>>> f._instance_setitem = types.MethodType(new_setitem, f, Foo)
>>> f[0] = 0
new setitem
```