# Dynamically overriding __getitem__ at runtime?

Tags: python-2.7, object, magic-methods

I have a simple class (`class Cache(object):`, i.e. new type) that implements a caching scheme. The lookup in the cache happens through `__getitem__`. Now I wanted to implement a method to disable the cache entirely (effectively generating the content on the fly every time) and was setting an instance variable `self.disabled` to signal that condition.

Now the idea was, in `__init__` to do:

```
if self.disabled:
    self.__dict__['__getitem__'] = self.disabled___getitem__
```

alas, it doesn't take effect. The same happens when I use the alternative form:

```
if self.disabled:
    self.__getitem__ = self.disabled___getitem__
```

How do I check whether it works? Basically the default version of `__getitem__` has a line such as this:

```
if self.disabled:
    raise RuntimeError("This mustn't get called when the cache is disabled!")
```

the one supposed to be used doesn't have that line.

When I changed `class Cache(object):` to `class Cache:` I ended up getting empty items, but no exception either.

How can I properly override `__getitem__` dynamically at runtime?

Note: I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281760/476371) to no avail.

Comment: Why would you do it that way round rather than making `__getitem__` just not do the check if it's disabled?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: because the check of that property can be expensive in my case. There is a reason even if I skip it to make the question more succinct.

Comment: If the statement `if not self.disabled:` is too slow for your case, then CPython is the wrong language environment for you. I'd suggest trying writing your cache in C or using PyPy. If you don't *know* that it's too slow on account of not having tried it—that's squarely in the category of premature optimisation.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I know that it's slow, because there are calls involved. So it makes sense to replace the respective object methods (e.g. `__getitem__`) here.

Comment: Have you *measured* the performance cost of introducing that extra conditional? Really, do no worry about it until you have *tried* it and *know* it to be slowing you down. Benchmark the four variants: `__getitem__` enabled, `__getitem__` disabled, and `__getitem__` supporting both cases with it both enabled and disabled. Then see how much slower it *actually* is.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: yes, measured it. Remember that accessing property can cause the invocation of extra code in Python. This is what's happening. Since all documentation claims that functions are first-class citizens in Python I expected to be able to overwrite the class method dynamically. Even if there wasn't the performance issue I'd still uphold my question out of curiosity, because it makes no sense that some functions can be reassigned and some can't.

Comment: I was assuming that `disabled` was a regular attribute, not a property. You certainly don't want it being an expensive call. If it is indeed a property which is anything but trivial, arrange for it to be a regular attribute. That should fix the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the wrong way around; you should instead make your `__getitem__` change its behaviour if `self.disabled`:

```
class Cache(object):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if not self.disabled:
            if ((ITEM_IS_CACHED)):
                return ((VALUE))
        # Cache miss, or cache disabled
        ((CALCULATE_ITEM))
        return ((VALUE))
```

Comment: What if Cache is a class from an external package you don't control and want to monkeypatch?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon: monkey-patching is almost always a bad idea—even if it works now, you’re asking for trouble in the future, trouble that may be difficult to pinpoint. But the same principle applies, it’s just `Cache.__getitem__`, you can do what you like with it (so long as it’s not a C extension, generally).